# Mac App Store Approval Duration?

Tags: macos, app-store

Sort of out of the programming realm, but does anyone have a recent waiting time for the Mac App Store? I submitted mine a week ago and still nothing..

Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes at least 10-15 working days at the moment for a new app or a major update, 4-5 working days for minor updates.  Be patient, they are overloaded at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about Mac App but they take 4-5 Working Days to approve iOS(iPads and iPhones) App Acc.

What's your current status ?

If you are having much problems call them up and register a complaint.

Comment: Complaining wont help, apple doesn't care

Answer (score 0):

There is a website that now tracks this using crowd sourced data from twitter

http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/